# Content dives when clicking responsive ubermenu

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Currently I am using UberMenu on http://favoritefm.com. On the desktop, it looks great. I can click everything in the menu and the menu is laying over the main div. Just what I want.

However, when I click 'menu' on the responsive website, my content 'dives'. Like: it measures how big the ubermenu is, and then it takes space. Try it out to see what I mean. Is there any quick fix? I can't see anything odd in my CSS that causes it.

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 959px)
.ubermenu-responsive-default.ubermenu-responsive.ubermenu {
    position: absolute;
}
```